# android library for Gridview with both horizontal and vertical swipe

Tags: android, gridview, swipe

Is there any Android library that supports both horizontal and vertical swiping GridView?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for GridView, but here you can find a RecyclerView example with GridLayoutManager which scrolls in both ways.

https://github.com/devunwired/recyclerview-playground